# Xsl and JS : Open in same window

Tags: javascript, xslt

I've an xsl code within some JS code like this :

```
<a href="javascript:openFullscreen('xxxxxxxxx')"> 
    <img xsl:use-attribute-sets="MY_IMG"/>
</a>
```

This href is targeting the same page it's in. But if i click on it, it open another window.

How can i open this in the same window ?

---

[EDIT]

I actually found a "solution"

```
  javascript:('top.close();openFullscreen(xxxxxx)')
```

Thanks

Comment: you'll have to show the javascript that's inside function 'openFullscreen()' as well...

Comment: I actually found a "solution" : javascript:('top.close();openFullscreen()') !